# What is the meaning of replace('\0','0')?

Tags: java, string, replace

I am following a tutorial and I came across this line of code:

```
String target = new String(new char[difficulty]).replace('\0', '0');
```

(`difficulty` is an `int`)

What does this line do and how does it work?

Comment: May be try `\\0`

Comment: @RehanAzher Maybe read the question again

Comment: you dont understand what the command does, or why it is doing it? search what String.replace() is in java and you will understand the command. if you dont know the the purpose of that command, i am afraid I can not help you. It might have to do with the fact that C applications uses `\0` to terminate a string line(as far as I know), where java doesnt

Comment: It just creates a `String` of `0`s, `difficulty` characters long.  i.e. if `difficulty` is `5`, then `target` is `"00000"`.

Comment: OK Got confused with the question title, yes @JacobG. is correct.

Comment: Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`new char[difficulty]` creates a new character array of length `difficulty`.

Elements of arrays created in this way take on [the default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of that type, which for `char` is `0` (or `'\u0000'` or `\0`), which is the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

`new String(...)` turns that into a string of length `difficulty` (where each character still has the default value of `0`.

`.replace('\0', '0')` replaces each of the characters with `'0'` (the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) `0` character) to give you a string of `difficulty` characters which are all `0`.